# AspNetMx Emaild Validation with c# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, email

I am trying the aspNetMx API. I would like to know the following figures. 
Checking the email is valid or invalid.

1. If email is valid (means domain is valid and user also exists) => flag as valid (eg. X)
2. If email is invalid, => flag as invalid (eg. Y)

   2.1. which is due to bad email syntax (eg. Y1)

   2.2. which is due to bad email domain (eg. Y2)

   2.3 which is due to bad mailbox (eg. Y3)

The following are different levels that aspNetMX validates the email addresses.

```
MXValidateLevel.NotValid

MXValidateLevel.Syntax

MXValidateLevel.MXRecords

MXValidateLevel.GreyListed

MXValidateLevel.SMTP

MXValidateLevel.Mailbox
```

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check the docs online : Taken from http://www.aspnetmx.com/help/index.htm

```
MXValidate mx = new MXValidate();

string email = "test@hotmail.com";
MXValidateLevel level = mx.Validate( email, MXValidateLevel.Mailbox );

switch( level )
{
case MXValidateLevel.NotValid:
//bad email address, remove from email address list
break;

case MXValidateLevel.Syntax:
//the email address is syntactically correct
break;

case MXValidateLevel.MXRecords:
//mx records were found, but for some reason
//the SMTP server couldn't be found
//save email for checking later, and see if SMTP servers fail again
break;

case MXValidateLevel.SMTP:
//able to connect to the mail server
//but mail server said email address was bad
//remove from list
break;


case MXValidateLevel.Greylisted:
//able to connect to the mail server
//but mail server said email address was greylisted
//for a later time.
//try back later
break;

case MXValidateLevel.Mailbox:
//the email address validated to the mail box `enter code here`level
//and the mail server will accept email for that address
break;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I found the docs but I don't know how to flag as valid or invalid.

Comment: From Docs - "When Validate() is executed, it attempts to validate an email address UP TO the level that was specified. If the validation was successful, it returns that level. If the validation was NOT successful, it returns the last highest level of validation that was found. This allows you to vary actions, based upon the level of validation returned."