# how to check for email existence or to find that it has bounced?

Tags: asp.net, email, outlook, smtp

My application send emails to clients, but now user wants to know whether mail exists or not before sending it, or give notification that email bounced back.

How can i test whether the email inputted by User exists or not before sending mail using C# asp.net
if not that then can we check if the mail has been bounced.

1. I saw TELNET command but it was not working.
2. I came across something ListNanny ( don't really know how to use it)
3. I also found  VRFY and RCPT ( didn't really looked much on that as of now)

please let me know if anyone has done similar kind of work in their project or POC. Meanwhile I am also looking for solutions.

We are using SMTP server for sending emails and our application is in ASP.NET application.

here is the sample of my code:

```
 var host = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[Constants.AppSettings.SMTP_HOST];
            var emailFromAddress = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[Constants.AppSettings.EMAIL_FROM_ADDRESS];
            var emailFromName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[Constants.AppSettings.EMAIL_FROM_NAME];
           
            using (var mail = new MailMessage())
            {
                mail.Body = body;
                mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(emailTo))
                    foreach (var email in emailTo.Split(Constants.Default.EMAILID_SEPARATOR))
                        mail.To.Add(new MailAddress(email));
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(emailCC))
                    foreach (var email in emailCC.Split(Constants.Default.EMAILID_SEPARATOR))
                        mail.CC.Add(new MailAddress(email));
                mail.From = new MailAddress(emailFromAddress, emailFromName);
                mail.Subject = subject;
                mail.Priority = MailPriority.High;
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(attachmentFilePath))
                    mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(attachmentFilePath));
                using (var smtp = new SmtpClient())
                {
                    smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                    smtp.Host = host;
                    smtp.Send(mail);

                }
            }
```

Thanks.

Comment: its too complicate (and not fast)... aspNetEmail , an old library have this functionality... - yes ListNanny the same company of aspNetEmail - ListNanny is the faster solution

Comment: @Aristos , can you show me an example of Listnanny , i saw some exaple on ther site they are using NAR file , i am not sure how to generate that. can you explain please

Comment: I also find this answer just now https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24733120/aspnetmx-emaild-validation-with-c-sharp-asp-net

Comment: @Aristos, okay let me try it. Thanks for your efforts :)

Comment: @aristos, it's not working, no matter what email id I select it gives me syntax in the level put.

Comment: I do not know what you do wrong, its working fine to me.

Comment: Can it be blocked by my organization server or firewall ??

Answer (score 1):

an example using the library `aspNetMX` that we talk about on the comments.

```
aspNetMX.MXValidate mx = new aspNetMX.MXValidate();

// your server infos
mx.SMTPHello = "www.site.com";
mx.SMTPFrom = "info@site.com";

aspNetMX.MXValidateLevel level = mx.Validate("testme@onesite.com", aspNetMX.MXValidateLevel.Mailbox);

if (level == aspNetMX.MXValidateLevel.Mailbox)
{
    // Valid email address.
}
else
{
    // NOT valid email address.
}
```